# HttpURLConnection getResponseCode() returns 200 in code but in the dev tools inspector it is actually 500

Tags: java, selenium, httpurlconnection

I am testing broken links, using HttpURLConnection when i run the script i get response code as 200 but it is actually 500

```
    Request URL: https://rb-upgrade.extranet-system.com/v2/social/rooms
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 500 
    Remote Address: 54.79.47.209:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://rb-upgrade.extranet-system.com/v2/social/rooms").openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
    int iresponsecode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

I get int iresponsecode as 200

How to make sure i get the correct response code as shown in the Developer tools. Thanks for your time

Comment: kind of hard for us to help out since the url is not resolvable (guess it is an internal url...).
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: rb-upgrad.extran-system.com`

Comment: https://rb-upgrade.extranet-system.com/v2/social/rooms

Comment: please find the correct url

Comment: works fin for me I get a 200 and a redirect to https://rb-upgrade.extranet-system.com/v2/login

Comment: final String GET_RESPONSE_CODE_SCRIPT =   "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +  "xhr.open('GET', arguments[0], false);" +   "xhr.send(null);" +  "return xhr.status";                                                                                                                        
                        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
Object obj = new Object();
       
  obj=javascriptExecutor.executeScript(GET_RESPONSE_CODE_SCRIPT, "https://rb-upgrade.extranet-system.com/v2/social/rooms");      
  System.out.println("response code is  ::" + obj);

Comment: This way i could get the correct response 500 , i still not sure why first approach did not work.